# Merge pandas DataFrame columns starting with the same letters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Let's say I have a `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a1':[1,2],'a2':[3,4],'b1':[5,6],'b2':[7,8],'c':[9,0]})
>>> df
   a1  a2  b1  b2  c
0   1   3   5   7  9
1   2   4   6   8  0
>>>
```

And I want to merge (maybe not merge, but concatenate) the columns where their name's first letter are equal, such as `a1` and `a2` and others...  but as we see, there is a `c` column which is by itself without any other similar ones, therefore I want them to not throw errors, instead add `NaN`s to them.

I want to merge in a way that it will change a wide `DataFrame` into a long `DataFrame`, basically like a wide to long modification.

I already have a solution to the problem, but only thing is that it's very inefficient, I would like a more efficient and faster solution (unlike mine :P), I currently have a `for` loop and a `try` `except` (ugh, sounds bad already) code such as:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame()
>>> for i in df.columns.str[:1].unique():
    try:
        df2[i] = df[[x for x in df.columns if x[:1] == i]].values.flatten()
    except:
        l = df[[x for x in df.columns if x[:1] == i]].values.flatten().tolist()
        df2[i] = l + [pd.np.nan] * (len(df2) - len(l))


>>> df2
   a  b    c
0  1  5  9.0
1  3  7  0.0
2  2  6  NaN
3  4  8  NaN
>>>
```

I would like to obtain the same results with better code.

Comment: Why is c=0. aligned with (a, b) = (3, 7) in the new dataframe while in there is no connection between them in the original dataframe?

Comment: @GZ0 my answer gives the exact output. `3,7` are 2nd horizontally while `0` is 2nd vertically.

Comment: I know. I'm just questioning whether the output is really desired or not. It seems to me that it would be more reasonable to align c=0. with (a, b) = (2, 6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({i: pd.Series(x.to_numpy().ravel()) 
                      for i, x in df.groupby(lambda x: x[0], axis=1)})
print (df)
   a  b    c
0  1  5  9.0
1  3  7  0.0
2  2  6  NaN
3  4  8  NaN
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend `melt`, followed by `pivot`. To resolve duplicates, you'll need to pivot on a cumcounted column.

```
u = df.melt()
u['variable'] = u['variable'].str[0]  # extract the first letter
u.assign(count=u.groupby('variable').cumcount()).pivot('count', 'variable', 'value')

variable    a    b    c
count                  
0         1.0  5.0  9.0
1         2.0  6.0  0.0
2         3.0  7.0  NaN
3         4.0  8.0  NaN
```

This can be re-written as,

```
u = df.melt()
u['variable'] = [x[0] for x in u['variable']]
u.insert(0, 'count', u.groupby('variable').cumcount())

u.pivot(*u)

variable    a    b    c
count                  
0         1.0  5.0  9.0
1         2.0  6.0  0.0
2         3.0  7.0  NaN
3         4.0  8.0  NaN
```

---

If performance matters, here's an alternative with `pd.concat`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

pd.concat({
    k: pd.Series(g.values.ravel()) 
    for k, g in df.groupby(operator.itemgetter(0), axis=1)
}, axis=1)

   a  b    c
0  1  5  9.0
1  3  7  0.0
2  2  6  NaN
3  4  8  NaN
```

Comment: The output is a little different from OP's expected, thanks to @GZ0's comment. But I guess it's not that important.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yeah, I assumed relative ordering was not important for OP, but they may want to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

We can try groupby columns (`axis=1`):

```
def f(g,a):
    ret = g.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
    ret.name = a
    return ret

pd.concat( (f(g,a) for a,g in df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1)), axis=1)
```

output:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   5   9.0
1   3   7   0.0
2   2   6   NaN
3   4   8   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not as good as using melt , but since this push into one-line, if you do need a faster solution try cs95's solution

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str[0],1).agg(lambda x : x.tolist()).sum().apply(pd.Series).T
Out[391]: 
     a    b    c
0  1.0  5.0  9.0
1  3.0  7.0  0.0
2  2.0  6.0  NaN
3  4.0  8.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `rename` and `groupby.apply`:

```
df = (df.rename(columns = dict(zip(df.columns, df.columns.str[:1])))
        .groupby(level=0, axis=1, group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values.flat, columns=np.unique(x.columns))))

print(df)
   a  b    c
0  1  5  9.0
1  3  7  0.0
2  2  6  NaN
3  4  8  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.concat` with `pd.melt` and `pd.groupby`:

```
pd.concat([d.T.melt(value_name=k)[k] for k, d in df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], 1)], 1)
```

Output:

```
   a  b    c
0  1  5  9.0
1  3  7  0.0
2  2  6  NaN
3  4  8  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution gives a similar answer to cs95's and is two to three times faster.

```
grouping = df.columns.map(lambda s: int(s[1:]) if len(s) > 1 else 1)
df.columns = df.columns.str[0]   # Make a copy if the original dataframe needs to be retained
result = pd.concat((g for _, g in df.groupby(grouping, axis=1)), 
                   axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Output

```
    a   b   c
0   1   5   9.0
1   2   6   0.0
2   3   7   NaN
3   4   8   NaN
```

Comment: Wow, it is the fastest

Comment: Well, jezrael beat you with miliseconds :P

Comment: Thanks. In my testing enviroment my solution is slightly faster than his even if I make a copy of the original data. If I don't make the copy it would be 50% faster.

Comment: You may want to have a look at my comment under the problem statement and see whether you want to add some clarification about the desired output.

Comment: I am the OP, :P

Comment: My output is slightly different from your desired output (like cs95's) and I think this is more reasonable than what you provided. I gave explanations under the problem statement. Other solutions give exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Your is the same as my desired output, which is more reasonable, yes. i agree with you

Comment: @U9-Forward - Answer is wrong, check first column - order is different. `1,2,3,4`, but need `1,3,2,4`